# Android library project returns incorrect resources

Tags: android, android-resources, android-library

I'm having trouble with resources in my Android library project. The library project consists of it's source already compiled in .class files in JARs and the resources in the `res` folder. The classes were compiled with the `--non-constant-id` AAPT option.

In my library project I have:

```
res/drawable/image1.png
res/drawable/image3.png
```

In the project dependent on the library project I have:

```
res/drawable/image2.png
```

Eclipse creates an R.txt and R.java for each project. So in total there's two R.txt's and two R.java's.

In the library project's R.java, the resource IDs are as such:

```
image1=0x7f02007c;
image3=0x7f02007d;
```

A library project means that this R.java file will be merged with the dependent project's R.java yielding a final R.java that looks like:

```
image1=0x7f02007c;
image2=0x7f02007d;
image3=0x7f02007e;
```

As expected, the inclusion of `image2` shifted the memory locations down by 1 in the final R.java.

**The problem**: When I reference a resource, like `R.drawable.image3`, from the JARs in my library project, it resolves to the ID in the non-merged R.java. For example: `R.drawable.image3 = 0x7f02007d`. But `0x7f02007d` actually points to `image2` and thus, the wrong resource is returned. I assume I am doing something wrong. Does anyone have any ideas as to what that may be?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the generated code to allow it to regenerate?

Comment: @BobbyDigital Yes, I have cleaned both of the projects and confirmed that both the `R.txt` and `R.java` files were, in fact, deleted.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I solved the problem. Turned out the JARs in the library project were being built incorrectly (something specific to my build system). Sorry to anyone that comes across this question while searching; it won't be very helpful.

Comment: i am getting the same problem with my JAR file and not able to get the correct resources.Please help if you can.

Comment: @PrabhjotSingh On SO, if you have a question you should open a new questions rather than piggybacking off an existing question. That said, look up the getIdentifer() function.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your build system and how you fixed it?  I'm experiencing this issue now.